# Making a blog the home page in PyroCMS

Tags: pyrocms

I know that I can go into pages and make an individual page the default home page, but how do I make a blog the home page in PyroCMS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to system/cms/config/routes.php and change the default controller to the blog module (around line 41).

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'blog';
```